# remove quotes from sql database name form c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am creating a table upon a button click based off a table name entered in a textBox. Everything is functional but I may be overlooking something as it relates to my table name in sql displaying with single quotes around it. eg. the name jevon would be shown as 'jevon' in the database. Is there a way to eliminate the single quotes? Is it an oversight in my implementation?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
        string query = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].['" + textBox1.Text + "'](" + "[Code] [varchar] (7) NOT NULL," +
       "[Description] [varchar] (38) NOT NULL," + "[NDC] [varchar] (12) NULL, " +
       "[Supplier Code] [varchar] (38) NOT NULL," + "[UOM] [varchar] (8) NULL," + "[Size] [varchar] (8) NULL,)";


        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes, entity names should never be surrounded by quotes:

```
string query = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + textBox1.Text + "](.....
```

And a note: it is bad style to use an unverified string like this, the user could type all kinds of stuff that totally destroys your database... so it looks more like an exercise than something serious anyway.